# OpenCMS add property to a page

Tags: jsp, opencms

I'm trying to use this module on opencms:

http://www.codedroids.com/en/opencms/downloads/com.codedroids.oc.forms.html

I am following the documentation: http://www.codedroids.com/export/download/pub/forms-guide.pdf

It says "add those properties to the page: MailSubject, Form, MailTo, MailFrom, etc" but how do I exactly add them? Is there some tag to be used? Or should I declare them as variables on the page? I tried many things without success.

For what I saw in the included jsp file those properties are read using cms.property("PropertyName", null, null); but I have no clue on how to declare them.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OpenCMS Explorer view, right click a file, select "Properties"

On the Properties screen, click Advanced.

On the Advanced screen, scroll to the bottom, and there's a "Define" button.

The define button takes you to a screen where you can define new properties.  These apply to all files (I think).

Hope that helps.